# React: how to move a function out of the render() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, sorry if I don't have the terminology down.

I've been given some work to change an existing React component and update a value that it displays.

Right now the render function returns a dialogue field with a bunch of data:

```
render() {
    const { selectedDate, labelText, dialogTitle, ...props } = this.props

return (
      <DialogField
        name="dialog-field"
        labelText={floatingLabelText}
        dialogTitle={dialogTitle}
        errorText="Please check your selection"
        userFriendlyValue={
          selectedDate
            ? [this.dateUtil.translateMonthShort(selectedDate.getMonth()), selectedDate.getFullYear()].join(' ')
            : ''
        }
      >
      </DialogField>
     )
```

I want to take the function in `userFriendlyValue` and abstract that into its own stand-alone function. To do that I have added the following above the render function:

```
userFriendlyDate() {
    selectedDate
      ? [this.dateUtil.translateMonthShort(selectedDate.getMonth()), selectedDate.getFullYear()]
      .join(' ')
      : 'ERROR'
  }
```

Added this in my `constructor()`:

```
this.userFriendlyDate = this.userFriendlyDate.bind(this)
```

And updated the returned element:

```
    return (
      <DialogField
        name="dialog-field"
        labelText={floatingLabelText}
        dialogTitle={dialogTitle}
        errorText="Please check your selection"
        userFriendlyValue={this.userFriendlyDate}
      >
      </DialogField>
    )
```

But this doesn't work. It doesn't throw any errors but doesn't show any value either.

Would anyone know what I've done wrong and how I should abstract this function?

Comment: You aren't actually returning anything from `userFriendlyDate`, therefore there is no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning any value in the funciton.

```js
  userFriendlyDate() {
    return selectedDate
      ? [this.dateUtil.translateMonthShort(selectedDate.getMonth()), selectedDate.getFullYear()]
      .join(' ')
      : 'ERROR'
  }
```

And I think you should call it, not bind it.

```js
userFriendlyValue={this.userFriendlyDate()}
```

Answer (score 0):

> [**componentDidMount()**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) : Best way to update the `props` and `states` are the `componentDidMount` life cycle method of the reactjs.